# Logging out programmatically after providing credentials using HttpClient

Tags: java, http, authentication, httpclient, apache-httpclient-4.x

I'm using the Apache HttpClient 4.3.4 library in Java to programmatically provide credentials to a URL that requires authentication. This is what I have in my code:

```
public static void clientAuthentication() throws Exception {
    CredentialsProvider credsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();

    credsProvider.setCredentials(
            AuthScope.ANY,
            new UsernamePasswordCredentials("username", "password"));

    CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.custom()
            .setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credsProvider)
            .build();

    try {
        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://www.example.com");

        System.out.println("Executing request " + httpget.getRequestLine());
        CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);

        try {
            System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
            System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());
            for (Header h : response.getAllHeaders()){
                System.out.println(h.toString());
            }

            EntityUtils.consume(response.getEntity());
        } finally {
            response.close();
        }
    } finally {
        httpclient.close();
    }
}
```

I'm able to successfully authenticate to the URL, as I'm getting a 200 status code. My question is, now that I have "logged in" programmatically, is there a way to "log out" programmatically? This URL doesn't have any "log out" button or anything similar; so I'm wondering how does one log out programmatically.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Logout i don't think so. you can use timeout method in httpclient.

```
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams, 30 *  1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

There should be an API end-point to logout. You need to call it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think HTTPS BASIC has a mechanism for logging out the session. (I am assuming your server uses BASIC auth).

The [rfc](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2617) says the session is valid until next authentication challenge is received. So an ugly way would be to make another auth attempt with incorrect credentials. But think before you do this, because too many incorrect auth attempts might have people think that you are bruteforcing the password.